# Tab bar cut off on Ionic Cordova application

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I'm having trouble with an Ionic tab application. At some point in modifying my code I noticed that my bottom tab bar was being cut off, however I'm not sure where in the process it happened and I have been unable to identify how it happened. It doesn't seem to be any CSS styling as I have explicitly set the boarder/padding/margin to 0 and still had this problem. I also tried raising the tab to see what it looked like at the top and I noticed a white bar above my tab bar. I don't know what that is from or how it got there and I assume that is my problem. It happens on Android, IOS device and SIM along with the web browser. Also it seems as though the tab title isn't coming through either. I'm sure it's all related but I don't know what to fix as I've checked all my files.

[image: Bottom cut off]

[image: Top cut off]

index.html

```
<body ng-app="cspapp">
    <!--
      The nav bar that will be updated as we navigate between views.
    -->
    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-positive">
        <ion-nav-back-button>
        </ion-nav-back-button>
    </ion-nav-bar>
    <!--
      The views will be rendered in the <ion-nav-view> directive below
      Templates are in the /templates folder (but you could also
      have templates inline in this html file if you'd like).
    -->
    <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
</body>
```

tabs.html

```
<ion-tabs class="tabs-icon-only tabs-positive">

    <ion-tab title="Home" icon="ion-home" ui-sref="tabs.home">
        <ion-nav-view name="home-tab"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-tab>

</ion-tabs>
```

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('cspapp', ['ionic', 'ionic.service.core', 'ionic.service.analytics', 'ngCordova',
    'cspapp.controllers', 'cspapp.services'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform, $ionicAnalytics) {
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function () {

        //Start analytics service
        //$ionicAnalytics.register();

        // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
        // for form inputs)
        /*
        if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
          cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
          cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);

        }
        if (window.StatusBar) {
          // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
          StatusBar.styleLightContent();
        }
        */
    });
})

.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $stateProvider
      .state('tabs', {
          url: "/tab",
          abstract: true,
          templateUrl: "templates/tabs.html"
      })
      .state('tabs.home', {
          url: "/home",
          views: {
              'home-tab': {
                  templateUrl: "templates/home.html",
                  controller: 'HomeTabCtrl'
              }
          }
      })
      .state('tabs.resources', {
          url: "/resources",
          views: {
              'home-tab': {
                  templateUrl: "templates/additionalresources.html",
                  controller: "AdditionalResourcesCtrl"
              }
          }
      })
      .state('tabs.gmetrics', {
          url: "/gmetrics",
          views: {
              'home-tab': {
                  templateUrl: "templates/global-metrics.html",
                  controller: "GlobalMetricsCtrl"
              }
          }
      })
      .state('tabs.gfeed', {
          url: "/gfeed",
          views: {
              'home-tab': {
                  templateUrl: "templates/global-feed.html",
                  controller: "GlobalFeedCtrl"
              }
          }
      })
      .state('tabs.googleforms', {
          url: "/googleforms",
          views: {
              'home-tab': {
                  templateUrl: "templates/googleforms.html",
                  controller: "GoogleFormsCtrl"
              }
          }
      })
      .state('tabs.social', {
          url: "/social",
          views: {
              'home-tab': {
                  templateUrl: "templates/social.html",
                  controller: "SocialNetworkCtrl"
              }
          }
      });
    /*
    .state('tabs.chapters', {
        url: "/chapters",
        views: {
            'home-tab': {
                templateUrl: "templates/chapters.html"
            }
        }
    });
    */
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/tab/home");

})

.config(['$ionicConfigProvider', function ($ionicConfigProvider) {


    $ionicConfigProvider.tabs.position('bottom'); //other values: top

}]);
```

Comment: Please paste your HomeTabCtrl code also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated your code in [git hub](https://github.com/anilkumar007/Ionic-Template) without any error's and it is worked for me, please have a look and reply if you have any questions

Comment: Thanks, I changed around my index.html and app.js to look like yours and I fixed my issue. I'm still not entirely sure what it actually was.

Comment: I have to revise your code again to understand what I have done.because I have done this work long time ago, by the end of the day I will tell you what I have done